# UIButton Interfering with UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I am using a custom subclass of an `MKButton` found [here](https://github.com/nghialv/MaterialKit/blob/master/Source/MKButton.swift) (which is a subclass of a `UIButton`).

I have a `UITableView` with X number of `UITableViewCell`s. Each of these cells has one or more `MKButton`'s in the tableView. The purpose of these cells is to open a link to a webpage when any of them are clicked.

Whenever I am scrolling through the `UITableView`, I will accidentally click one of the MKButtons. I cannot figure out how to prevent this.

I would like to be able to support iOS 7 and iOS 8 if that makes any difference.

I have looked around and have not been able to find much. Here is what I've tried so far:

- Setting the `delaysContentTouches` to YES.
- Setting the `canCancelContentTouches` to YES.
- Subclass `UITableView` and overriding `- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view` to return YES;

Comment: Where have you set `delaysContentTouches`? on the buttons or on the tableview?

Comment: I have set it on the `UITableView`

Comment: OK. Have you tried `canCancelContentTouches = YES` on the tableview?

Comment: Yes. I believe it is "YES" by default.

Comment: No, I think it's NO by default. That's usually what does it for the buttons. You could also try setting it on the buttons themselves (try both YES and NO)? And for good measure, set delaysContentTouches to NO too to test.

Comment: I couldn't seem to build the project because `MKButton does not have a member named delaysContentTouches`. Same applies for canCancelContentTouches. Setting it to NO did not seem to work either.

Comment: `delaysContentTouches` is a property of `UITableView` (`UIScrollView` to be specific)

Answer (score 0):

Just recognise if the table is moving or not and suppress the button clicks.

```
-(BOOL)isTableViewMoving
{
    return _tableView.isDragging || _tableView.isDecelerating;
}

-(void)didTapButton
{
if ( !isTableViewMoving)
  //dostuff
}
```

EDIT:

Found an even better solution: just use `UITapGestureRecognizer`. For some reason it works better than `touchUpInside`.